# Can someone please fix my search bar in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, search

I'm trying to make a searchbar, where I can search data from my Django API. Right now I can find shows by name, and when I'm deleting my prompt it doesn't update. I would also like to find shows by their directors for example. Can someone help me with this?

This is my search screen:

```
  List<ShowsModel> showsList = [];
  List<DirectorModel> directorList = [];

  Future<void> getShows() async {
    showsList = await APIHandler.getAllShows();
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<void> getDirectors() async {
    directorList = await APIHandler.getAllDirectors();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    getShows();
    getDirectors();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  void updateList(String value) {
    setState(() {
      showsList = showsList
          .where((element) =>
              element.name.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()))
          .toList() ; //i would like to add more elements here but don't know how
    });
  }

//skipping widget build
// my search bar
 Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color.fromRGBO(244, 243, 243, 1),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                  ),
                  child: TextField(
                    onChanged: (value) => updateList(value),
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          color: Colors.black87,
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
```